# Adding babel-polyfill to my webpack file when using an entries object

Tags: webpack

According to Babel polyfill's docs, I'm supposed to add it to my webpack config's `entry` value like this:

```
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/js']
```

However I specify my entry values with an object instead of an array:

```
entry: { app: './client' }
```

How should I add babel-polyfill?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an array as the value of `entry.app`:

```
entry: { app: [ "babel-polyfill", "./client" ] }
```

For details see [webpack's documentation of the `entry` option](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry). webpack 2 should behave the same way according to its [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry).

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple entries with object notation, for example:

```
  entry: {
    polyfill: resolve('src', 'config', 'polyfill.js'),
    vendor: resolve('src', 'config', 'vendor.js'),
    app: resolve('src', 'index.js')
  },
```

It is better to use separate entry for `babel-polyfill` because you may want to use [babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) with `useBuiltIns` option:

> This option enables a new plugin that replaces the statement import "babel-polyfill" or require("babel-polyfill") with individual requires for babel-polyfill based on environment.